# Creating dynamic amount of <asp:Image>

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to create dynamic amount of `asp:image` tag in my aspx code.

How can i do it?
I tried `response.write` inside `<%%>` with a for loop but it didn't work.
Any other ideas? Also it should be run at server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = "Sample Label";

Panel Panel1= new Panel();
Panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
```

adding this in your loop will generate controls dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You **CAN** do it with inline markup:

```
<% for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {%>
   <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="" />
<%}%>
```

This will generate 10 images of whatever.jpg.
One thing you can't do is put ASP controls in inline block: `<%...%> no ASP controls here <%...%>`.
Between `{%>` and `<%}%>` should only be pure HTML controls or text, no server controls.

If you **MUST** use server controls then you can do it in for loop in codebehind. Assuming you added `<asp:Placeholder ID="my_placeholder" runat="server"></asp:Placeholder>` in markup, you can do this in codebehind:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   Image img = new Image();
   img.Src = "whatever.jpg";
   this.my_placeholder.Controls.Add(img);
}
```